# Write similar logic using generics

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I have the following method which determines which cars I need to delete from the DB.

```
private List<CarDTO> BuildCarsToDelete(IList<CarDTO> newCars, IList<CarDTO> existingCars)
{
    var missingCars = new List<CarDTO>();

    var cars = newCars.Select(c => c.CarId);
    var newCarIds = new HashSet<int>(cars);

    foreach (var car in existingCars)
    {
        //If there are no new cars then it had some and they have been removed
        if (newCars.Count() == 0)
        {
            missingCars.Add(car);
        }
        else
        {
            if (!newCarIds.Contains(car.CarId))
            {
                missingCars.Add(car);
            }
        }
    }

    return missingCars;
}
```

This works as I want - but if I want to achieve the same functionality for Customers or Apartments of other DTOs I will be copying a pasting the code but only changing the variable names and the Type of DTO around - is there a nicer way possible using generics which would keep the algorithm and logic as it is but allow me to use on any DTO?

Comment: No, because you have a specific Id in `CarId`.  You would need to abstract that Id to something that could be contained by a common interface, unless you wanted to resort to reflection.

Comment: ok - so a better approach would be to have a Base Class with just Id and maybe some other common properties such as DateModified and then have other DTOs inherit from that

Comment: Either that, or an interface that exposes a common way of getting the `Id` for every entity type.

Comment: You'll need some sort of abstraction (interface, abstract base class, or just regular old base class).

Comment: Something like this `private List<T> BuildToDelete(IList<T> newItems, IList<T> existingItems, Func<T, int> getId)`.  Note you have to add a `Func` that will get the ids for you and they all have to be of type `int`.

Comment: This sounds a very opinion-based design question. It *might* be better asked over on [softwareengineering.se], but you'd want to read the help center over there and/or ask on their meta.

Comment: @juharr - would you mind expanding on this with an answer (mostly showing how the Func getId would work) as this may be the best approach for me rather than changing the complete underlying Data Model and DB

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If all the ids are of type `int` then you can do that by passing in a `Func` to determine the id.

```
private List<T> BuildToDelete<T>(
    IList<T> newItems, 
    IList<T> existingItems, 
    Func<T, int> getId)
{
    var missingItems = new List<T>();

    var items = newItems.Select(getId);
    var newItemIds = new HashSet<int>(items);

    foreach (var item in existingItems)
    {
        if (newItems.Count() == 0)
        {
            missingItems.Add(item);
        }
        else
        {
            if (!newItemIds.Contains(getId(item)))     
            {
                missingItems.Add(item);
            }
        }
    }

    return missingItems;
}
```

Then call as shown below:

```
var results = BuildToDelete(newCars, existingCars, c => c.CarId);
```

Comment: Cheers - you were 2 steps ahead of my comment - ill give this a go

Comment: If having to change your whole data model is a concern, I would definitely  go this route over the base class or interface.  You won't have to change anything, as long as the id field is always an `int`.

Comment: If the id can be something else you can make that another generic type.  Though you'll likely want to constrain that type to implementations of `IComparable<TId>`

Comment: @BradleyUffner - yeah the Id will always be an int - I was over ruled at the Dat Model design stage and it is now when you come to write this type of functionality you see where the benefits would have been

Comment: hi @juharr - when I add the private method I am getting an error - The type or namespace 'T' cannot be found.  My CarDTO is just a POCO class

Comment: @Ctrl_Alt_Defeat Yeah, I forgot to define it on the method.  I've fixed that now, by adding the `<T>` after `BuildToDelete`.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you use the interface approach mentioned in comments, a generic version could look something like this:

```
private List<TEntity> BuildEntitiesToDelete(IList<TEntity> newEntities, IList<TEntity> existingEntities) where TEntity : IEntityWithId
{
    var missingEntities = new List<TEntity>();

    var entities = newEntities.Select(e => e.Id);
    var newEntityIds = new HashSet<int>(entities);

    foreach (var entity in existingEntities)
    {
        if (entities.Count() == 0)
        {
            missingEntities.Add(entity);
        }
        else
        {
            if (!newEntityIds.Contains(entity.Id))
            {
                missingEntities.Add(entity);
            }
        }
    }

    return missingEntities;
}
```

`IEntityWithId` is probably a poor name for the interface, but I'll leave picking a better name up to you.

Answer (score 0):

Try something cleaner:

1) create flexible equality comparer (need to add some null checking etc.)

```
public class FuncEqualityComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<T>
{
    Func<T, T, bool> comparer;
    Func<T, int> hash;

    public FuncEqualityComparer (Func<T, T, bool> comparer, Func<T, int> hash)
    {
        this.comparer = comparer;
        this.hash = hash;
    }

    public bool Equals (T x, T y) => comparer (x, y);

    public int GetHashCode (T obj) => hash (obj);
}
```

2) and now, just simply:

```
var carComparerByID = new FuncEqualityComparer<CarDTO> ((a, b) => a.CarId == b.CarId, x => x.CarId.GetHashCode ());

var result = existingCars.Except (newCars, carComparerByID).ToList ();
```